# Ruby - How many days?

Tags: ruby, time

I need to calculate how many days lived on earth based on three parameters : day, month and year.
I don't know how to convert the input onto a date; and then how to convert the date onto number of days.
This is my code for the moment...

```
require 'date'
def age_in_days(day, month, year)
  lived = (day+"-"+month+"-"+year).to_s
  date_lived Date.parse(lived)
  return (Date.today - date_lived).to_i
end
```

Comment: I think you forgot the code, please edit your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a [`Date`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-new) object directly with:

```
Date.new(year, month, day)
```

There's no need to convert it to a string and parse. Parsing could also be dangerous. Is `1982-04-02` the 4th of February or 2nd of April?

You cannot add a number and string like this, BTW. Should `1 + '2'` be `'12'` or `3`? Ruby cannot decide for you so you need to explicitly convert integers to string.

```
day.to_s + "-" + month.to_s + "-" + year.to_s
```

or simply

```
[day, month, year].join('-')
```

But you don't need it anyway:

```
require 'date'

def age_in_days(day, month, year)
  birthdate = Date.new(year, month, day)
  (Date.today - birthdate).to_i
end
```